# Repeat code on button click with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I want to create a page where you can add from 1 to n products dinamically.

I've been working with AngularJS for a couple of months but it's kind of difficult for me to think this.

The html code I tought about it's something like this:

https://plnkr.co/edit/2MYbkYeAf4lZSRIh2c8l?p=preview

Here it is the entire template:

```
<div class="container text-center">
    <h1>Make a sale</h1>
    <br>
    <form>
        <div class = "divedp">
            <label for="idNumeroFactura" class="col-form-label" >Invoice number: </label>
            <input name="inpNumeroFactura" id="idNumeroFactura" maxlength= "8" type="text" ng-model="numeroFactura" class= "form-control"/>
        </div>
        <h6 class="small">products</h6>
        <div class = "divedp">
            <label for="idProducto">Product: </label>
            <select name="sltProducto" ng-options ="producto.nombreProducto for producto in productos"
                ng-model="producto" class="form-control input-sm" id="idProducto">
                <option value="">-Choose the product-</option>
            </select> 
             <br>
            <label for= "idCantidad" >Quantity: </label>
            <select ng-model="cantidad" id="idCantidad" class="form-control input-sm">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <button ng-click="showDiv=true; agregarProducto()" class="btn btn-default" ng-hide="showDiv"> Add another product</button>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="showDiv"> Here should appear the new product</div>

        <button ng-click="guardarVenta()" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save sale</button>
    </form>
    <span >{{mensaje}}</span> <br>
</div>
```

And this is the part I want to repeat:

```
<div class = "divedp">
    <label for="idProducto">Product: </label>
    <select name="sltProducto" ng-options ="producto.nombreProducto for producto in productos"
        ng-model="producto" class="form-control input-sm" id="idProducto">
        <option value="">-Choose the product-</option>
    </select> 
     <br>
    <label for= "idCantidad" >Quantity: </label>
    <select ng-model="cantidad" id="idCantidad" class="form-control input-sm">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
        <option value="7">7</option>
        <option value="8">8</option>
        <option value="9">9</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="showDiv=true; agregarProducto()" class="btn btn-default" ng-hide="showDiv"> Add another product</button>
    </div>
```

So when I click *add another product* button, all div code part should repeat below the first div. This way, the user can choose all products he want with the quantity he want.

I was thinking on creating a template, but this is already a template... I'm using ui-router to do the routering part, but I never repeated a template inside a template, and I never used a template inside a template at all.

Besides, this approach gives me some doubts:

- How can I concatenate an attribute on a Json array? (I use Json to communicate between frontend and backend)
- How can I avoid users to repeat the same product item? should I take this problem to an AngularJS controller or can I handle it with directives?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't show any controller, I can provide only abstract idea of solution. Here goes anyway.

**Repeating**

Simple looping over collection of data is done with `ngRepeat`. In your controller, you need to manipulate the collection and angular will propagate the change for you

```
<div ng-repeat="productBlock in productBlocks track by productBlock.id">
    <!-- your repeated code here -->
    <button ng-click="removeProductBlock(productBlock.id)"> remove </button>
</div>
<button ng-click="addProductBlock()"> add </button>
```

[ngRepeat documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

**Prohibiting user from selecting duplicate product**

You can achieve this, again, with manipulating a collection in your controller. This time, the collection would hold products still available to choose. Angular will help you with propagating the change from controller to your view with the `ngOptions` directive

```
<select 
    ng-options="product as product.label for product in productsAvailable track by product.id"        
    ng-change="selectProduct(product.id)">
</select>
```

The `selectProduct` method will be responsible for removing the product from `productsAvailable` collection. 
Keep in mind that it also has to "put back" any products not being used on update.

[ngOptions documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: This seems like a good approach, let me work on this and I let you know.

Comment: Look, here I made a plnkr https://plnkr.co/edit/2MYbkYeAf4lZSRIh2c8l?p=preview . Can you be more specific now, please? I already read the angular document on repeat but I still don't get it for templates instead of objects.

Comment: Yes I'm working on this... you asked more code so I give you that. I don't accept your answer because I still can't prove it so chill out man. Thanks and bye